# how to send two steps verification enabled gmail using SMTP or PHP mailer?

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I set the two step verification option in gmail. I tried to send mail using SMTP and PHP mailer but its not sending. But if i turn off the two step verification option from gmail i am able to send mail using SMTP and PHP Mailer .. 
so can anyone tell me how to send two step verification enabled mail using SMTP?

Comment: I think its not possible  because its not in google term and policy..If you know that than ask question to google

Comment: have you installed sendmail....locally..it is a mail server that works with PHP

Comment: i am using Php mailer class to send email

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the one posted. It's not a question about how to send email, but of how to use Gmail's XOAUTH2 authentication system. The answer is very simple: [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2).